# How to add attachement in hangouts chat bot reply

Tags: attachment, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I created a bot in hangouts chat and also used the card message reply api.

I need to attach an image

```
{
  "cards": [
    {
      "sections": [
        {
          "widgets": [
            {
              "image": {
                "imageUrl": "https://example.com/kitten.png",
                "onClick": {
                  "openLink": {
                    "url": "https://example.com/"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This was the code given by them for adding an image. But I have the image locally and want to send it as an attachment. How can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create an account with a site like Imgur, upload your images, and then swap out your link for imageUrl.